# Makefile Errors: make all command

Tags: makefile

This is the makefile:

```
all: main

main: main.o sum/sum.o sum/add/add.o utils/utils.o
    gcc -Wall main.o sum/sum.o sum/add/add.o utils/utils.o -o main

main.o: main.c utils/utils.h sum/sum.h
    gcc -Wall -c main.c

sum/sum.o: sum/sum.c sum/sum.h add/add.h
    gcc -Wall -c sum/sum.c

sum/add/add.o: sum/add/add.c add.h
    gcc -Wall -c sum/add/add.c

utils/utils.o: utils/utils.c
    gcc -Wall -c utils/utils.c

clean:
    rm -f main main.o sum/sum.o sum/add/add.o utils/utils.o *~
```

When I run `make all` in bash, I get errors like:

```
-make: *** No rule to make target `add.h', needed by `sum/sum.o'.  Stop.

-make: *** No rule to make target `sum.c', needed by `sum/sum.o'.  Stop.
```

And I have a directory where everything is:

```
.:
main.c  main.o  Makefile  sum  utils

./sum:
add  sum.c  sum.h

./sum/add:
add.c  add.h

./utils:
utils.c  utils.h
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You have path confusion in this makefile. You list both `add/add.h` **and** `add.h`. I'm also not sure this makefile actually generated that exact output since it doesn't list `sum.c` but the error does. Are you sure this is the error from this exact makefile?

Comment: yes, this is the error.

Comment: I just copied that exact makefile and dir structure and running `make -nk` here gets me an error about `add/add.h` and `add.h` but nothing about `sum.c`. So I ask again. Are you **sure** you have that **exact** makefile and that **exact** file layout and that running `make` gets you **exactly** that output? (Because running just `make` should stop after the first `add/add.h` error.)

Comment: Oh, and fixing the paths to `add.h` makes things work correctly here.